# ERROR Failed to compile with 1 errors This dependency was not found:

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting an error in vue component when i try to import another javascript file that is in this directory services/AuthenticationService

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/services/AuthenticationService'
>   To install it, you can run: npm install --save @/services/AuthenticationService

I have searched for solution to this problem  but i can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated

This is my view component register.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
<h1>Register</h1>
     <input type="email" name="email" v-model ="email" placeholder="email"> <br>
     <input type="password" name="password" v-model ="password" placeholder="password"> <br>
      <button @click="register">
      Register
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
  async register(){
  const response = await AuthenticationService.register({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      })
  console.log(response.data)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Try to use relative import instead of `@/services/AuthenticationService` you should do `./services/AuthenticationService` assuming is on the same level directory of your register.vue or `../services/AuthenticationService` if you need to go a level up.

Comment: I deleted everything and started again and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have resolve in your webpack config?

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve('path/to/your/source/folder')
  }
}
```

Document https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: I don't have webpack config file in my project.